# Вставка, разбивающая реплику (пунктуация)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, прямая-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможна ли такая пунктуация?

```
— Пойду я домой. — Иванов махнул рукой в сторону. — Домой мне надо.
```

Считается ли здесь предложение "Иванов махнул рукой в сторону" словами автора? Нужно ли ставить запятую после "Пойду я домой"? Или все-таки нужна точка? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вы соединили всё в одну фразу с помощью тире, то это точно слова автора, тем более, что там описание жеста. Вот только в таком случае это не реплики, а обычная прямая речь, нужны кавычки:

" Пойду я домой, — Иванов махнул рукой в сторону. — Домой мне надо".

Если это отдельные реплики, то будет выглядеть так:

— Пойду я домой.

Иванов махнул рукой в сторону.

— Домой мне надо.

Или:

— Пойду я домой.

Иванов махнул рукой в сторону: "Домой мне надо."

Answer (score 0):

В трёх кряду фразах, в части пунктуации, как прямая речь однотипно оформленных (чего не должно быть), можно навести порядок, заменив точки / первую точку запятыми. Только тогда слова автора будут не угадываться, а сразу же узнаваться. Примеры возможного :

Слова автора внутри прямой речи.

```
«П, — а. — П». «Сегодня пишем диктант, — сказал учитель. — Открывайте тетради».
«П!?... — а. — П». «Готовы? — спросил учитель. — Тогда начинаем».
«П, — а, — п». «Ребята, — обратился учитель, — сегодня пишем диктант».
```

Ссылка: https://popravilam.com/blog/152-pryamaya-rech-skhemy.html